# How can I reliably log Pinterest follower count in spreadsheet with Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, pinterest

I'm looking to log Pinterest followers daily in a Google Spreadsheet. I'm using Blockspring for other social media platforms, but there is no block for Pinterest, so I'm thinking a google apps script or formula will be needed.

Thanks

Comment: Have you looked at the [pinterest API](https://developers.pinterest.com/)?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about this, but have a try. The Analytics service allows you to use the Google [Analytics Management API](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/) and [Reporting APIs](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/) in Apps Script. These APIs gives Analytics users the ability to get information about the structure of their account and run reports on how it is performing.